# I want to create a pandas DF based on 2 np.ranges tied together

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to create a pandas DF with 2 columns based on 2 np.arrays.

in the end it it should look like a dissolved x-y-matrix, since i have to test all X and Y combinations

example should be a DF with columns "X" and "Y"

```
 X      Y
----------
-5     -3
 0     -3
 5     -3
-5      0
 0      0
 5      0
-5      3
 0      3
 5      3
```

example starting condition:

```
a = np.arange(-5,6,5)
b = np.arange(-3,4,3)
```

I think if I create 2 np.arrays first and convert then to pandas.df will be much faster. I just don't find a solution to create these arrays first.

or does anybody have a better idea???

I have already found a solution that uses 2 for-loops that add rows to an empty DF. That is extremely slow and stupid!

Comment: `pd.MultiIndex.from_product((a,b)).to_frame()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use `itertools.product` and `from_records`:

```
from itertools import product
```

<strike>df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([i for i in product(a,b)])</strike>
    Actually, you don't need the list comprehension

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(product(a,b))
df
```

Output:

```
   0  1
0 -5 -3
1 -5  0
2 -5  3
3  0 -3
4  0  0
5  0  3
6  5 -3
7  5  0
8  5  3
```